# Access u-boot variable from kernel userspace

Tags: linux-kernel, yocto, u-boot

I was trying to get a u-boot variable from logo.c(/drivers/video/logo/logo.c). Please let me know how can I access the variable from logo.c file. I want to get the value of console. If I use "fw_printenv console" command, the output is console=ttys0. I want to get the output value of the u-boot variable(fw_printenv console) from logo.c.

Comment: drivers/video/logo/logo.c does not exist in current U-Boot. What version are you relating to? | What do you mean by kernel userspace? From a Linux program? Inside the U-Boot code? | Inside U-Boot code environment variables can be accessed via env_get().

Comment: @Xypron, it's a Linux kernel source.

Comment: See how `fw_printenv` works. I bet it reads the file from filesystem. This is not easy task for kernel especially on the early stages when many subsystems have been not initialized yet. Can't you use kernel command line instead?

Answer (score 0):

In u-boot : add *console=ttys0* to **bootargs**

```
setenv bootargs console=ttys0
```

---

In Kernel file : kernel_source/init/main.c

add early_param :

```
char MyConsole[32]={0};
static int __init myconsole(char *str)
{
    printk("%s\n", str);
    memcpy(MyConsole, str, strlen(str));
}
early_param("myconsole", myconsole);
```

---

In logo.c, Access this variable.

```
extern char MyConsole[];
```

---

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Could you please let me know which log or how can I see the output of " printk("%s\n", str). I was trying to see the output. I have logged in to the device while turning on, but it only shows the kernel messages.

Comment: Should I call "early_param("console", myconsole)"? or early_param("myconsole", myconsole) " is correct;

Comment: this one is correct : early_param("console", myconsole)